# Conclude woocommerce-shipping-totals

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I use a Plugin for my woocommerce Checkout (Fluid Checkout). I use different shipping Methods for different products. In this case I got for each Method one output in the checkout shipping totals.
But I want only one total for the output.
Here is the review-order.php with the code:

```
        <?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php // CHANGE: Replaced cart totals shipping markup with an action hook to allow for customizations ?>
        <?php do_action( 'fc_review_order_shipping' ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for Help.
Best Regards.
Marcel Rusche

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.